# Nodejs handle button/ajax requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I'm building a single page app and I was wondering if I'm actually doing it right. At the moment for each button that waits for a callback from the server I send an ajax request and on the server I handle it router.post/get like this:

index.html

```
<button id='baz' class'.foo'>Foo</button>
```

script.js

```
$(document).on('click', '.foo', function() {
    var cursor = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'modalRoutes/bar',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 5000,
        data: {
            baz: cursor.attr('id')
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            cursor.addClass('disabled');
        },
        complete: function() {
          cursor.removeClass('disabled');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // do somehting here
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

modalRoutes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.post('/bar', function(req,res){
  // do some stuff here
  res.send('done')
});
module.exports = router;
```

My modalRoutes.js file is growing, I barely started and it already has over 500 lines of code, is this the best way to handle buttons with node?

Comment: Look at this concept [pure-json-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pure-json-api).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have multiple modules, each exporting a default function, and just import them to have them apply onto the router, eg:

module code:

```
module.exports = function(router) {
  router.post('/buylicense', function() {
    // do some stuff here
    res.send('done');
  });
}
```

in modalRoutes, do:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
require('./someRoute')(router);
// add other imports here
module.exports = router;
```